# WPF button property binding to code

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to bind ribbon buttons property IsEnabled to code property so I can make it available or not to the user depending on a certain situation.

I don't know what I am doing wrong and I can't figure it out

Currently I have the following code.

The class ViewModel for the property and the event

```
Public Class ViewModel

Implements INotifyPropertyChanged



Private _btnStart As Boolean



Public Property btnStartVM() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _btnStart
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _btnStart = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("btnStartVM")
    End Set
End Property



Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub
```

End Class

Button declaration on the xaml

```
<RibbonButton x:Name="btnStart" Style="{StaticResource btnTriggers}"  SmallImageSource="Images/start.ico" Label="Start"/>
```

and the Style

```
<Style x:Key="btnTriggers" TargetType="{x:Type RibbonButton}">
     <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=btnStartVM , ElementName=btnStart}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=btnStartVM, ElementName=btnStart}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

Public Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    InitializeComponent()
    DataContext = New ViewModel()

    DataContext.btnStartVM = True
End Sub
```

The `DataContext.btnStartVM = True` does the job and it triggers the `NotifyPropertyChanged` but it dosen`t reflect back to the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property is named differently from the property you are reporting in your notification.

The property is named `btnStartVM` but you are reporting `btnStart`. Change the call to this:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("btnStartVM")
```

Additionally, the binding looks very off. You should probably remove the `, ElementName=btnStart` part.

Finally, you don't need to work with triggers here. The following style should work just as well:

```
<Style x:Key="btnTriggers" TargetType="{x:Type RibbonButton}">
  <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding btnStartVM}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I already modified this, question code was from an old source.

Comment: @user4141615: Please check the other two points I added to my answer.

Comment: Is still not working. The whole idea was to have one style with triggers so I could use it with multiple buttons and change the property value from the code.

Comment: As I said, you don't need triggers here. How are you actually using that style? Do you assign it to the ribbon buttons? Also, please note that with this style, you will enable or disable all buttons that use that style. You can't enable or disable them selectively. If that's what you want to do, simple add the binding directly on the respective buttons and use a different view model property each time

Comment: Yes. I assign it to the ribbon buttons. <RibbonButton x:Name="btnStart" Style="{StaticResource btnTriggers}"

Comment: Try using `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource`. Does it help?

Comment: I`v tried to use `DynamicResource ` and no luck also tried setting the binding directly to the property from the button `<RibbonButton x:Name="btnStart"  IsEnabled="{Binding btnStartVM}"/>` is not working either

Comment: @user4141615: Are the ribbon buttons actually in the window for which you set the data context?

Comment: The datacontext is set on a page load event that is loaded in to a frame on the mainwindow where the ribbonbuttons are located. On the page Ihave a list view and when i select an item from that listview i want to disable or enable the buttons from the mainwindow.

Comment: There you have your problem: You set the data context of the *page* but the ribbon buttons are in the *main window*. You need to set the data context of the *main window* for this to work.

Comment: so i should set this `DataContext = New ViewModel()` on the mainwindow load event?

Comment: adding `DataContext = New ViewModel()` to the mainwindow load event is working and allows me to modifiy the `IsEnabled` property from Enabled to disabled. It is not helping me as I can`t acces the datacontext from another window,usercontrol or page.

Comment: I have one more issue. When I modify the property from a buton click event on the mainwindow the binding works great calling the sub that I have created on the mainwindow class, but if I try to access the sub from a page and set the binding property it dosen`t work. My question is how can I modify the property from a page and reflect it back to the mainwindow? Cheers.